Need to reduce current to power station
I have a Bluetti EB240 I want to charge by hooking it up to existing on-the-roof solar panels.
The panels are putting out about 39V max and about 19A.
The EB240 max input is:  500W, 16-60V, 10A.
Is there a unit I could buy or home-build to reduce the current below 10A that someone knows of?
I have basic electronics training, but no design skills.
Thanks!!
don

Putting something inline is a bad idea, because of string mismatching. Just wire it from below

The cells do not 'put out' 19 A. They will allow a device to draw up to 19 A, (if there is sufficient illumination).
Just connect the inverter to the cells. It will only draw the current it wants to.
